# Message specification tool for a Message broker like RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, message-queue

I was inspired by the Swagger UI and rest API specifications it provides.

Recently I started to work with message brokers (in particular RabbitMQ) and I would like to have some tool to start development of a microservice oriented system with messages and queues specifications.

Is there any tool allowing to make these specifications? Generate docs from code or code from model?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**:

As described in [this](https://devops.datenkollektiv.de/creating-a-custom-rabbitmq-container-with-preconfigured-queues.html) post. Queue, exchange, buinding, useres and permissions can be described with RabbitMQ configuration files.

[AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/getting-started/) **looks like a good solution**

Comment: Try the rabbitmq management plugin. It provides some web-interface. 

if it is not what you are asking about, ... then let us know

Comment: Thanks for your comment, as far as I know RabbitMQ plugin doesn't capable of creating specification file. I would like to describe my queues and messages format in json (xml, yml) file and share it inside the tram as a specification. This will allow parallel work and possibly automate code writing, testing and documentation.

Comment: You can provide the queue and exchange configurations through a `json` file in `RabbitMQ`. The path to the json file must be specified in the `rabbitmq.conf` file.

Example: `management.load_definitions = /path/to/definitions.json`

Comment: If you use NServiceBus you get the Particular platform with ServiceInsight that gives you this: https://docs.particular.net/serviceinsight/ (Disclosure I work for Particular)

Comment: @bumblebee , thanks for your comment. It solves part of my task. Queue, exchange, bindings and users can be described in config files. Is there a way to specify messages format?

Comment: @SeanFarmar , thanks for your commetn. Looks like the NServiceBus is a useful tool for a message queue, but is it possible to create a message specification in this tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take a look to Async API, it is an initiative that starts like part of open api initiative (a.k.a swagger) but focused on event driven architectures using message brokers

https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/getting-started/